# Inserir tempo e hora na base de dados

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

Quero inserir separadamente a hora e a data na base de dados, que têm os campos `timestamp` e `data`, respetivamente.

Tenho o seguinte código no botão que faz a inserção:

```
SqlCommand sqlInsertCabecalho = 
new SqlCommand("Insert into cabecalho (nRequesicao,nomeEmpresa,colaborador,data,hora,nota) VALUES(@nRequesicao,@nomeEmpresa,@colaborador,@data,@hora,2nota)", sqlConn);

sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nRequesicao", nRequesicao.ToString());
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeEmpresa", DropDownListEmpresa.Text);
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colaborador", Session["New"].ToString());
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hora", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nota", TextBoxObservacoes.Text);

sqlConn.Open();
sqlTran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();
sqlInsertCabecalho.Transaction = sqlTran;
sqlInsertCabecalho.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlTran.Commit();
sqlConn.Close();

Response.Redirect("Consulta.aspx");
```

Mas no entanto recebo uma excepção e não faz a inserção. O que estou a fazer errado?

Comment: Diga qual é a exceção. Qual é o valor que está tentando usar? Eu faço uma ideia, mas não quero chutar.

Comment: @bigown Estou tentando usar o valor de data/hora atual automático, a execção diz que existe uma sintaxe incorreta.

Comment: @bigown Não sei se não estou a perceber a pergunta ou expliquei mal, mas quero inserir o valor da hora e data correntes de quando a inserção for feita. Daí o 'DateTime.Now'

Comment: É, tá certo, então o problema não é esse. Preciso de mais detalhe, a linha onde o erro ocorre, a exceção exata. Acho que o erro nem está nessas linhas, elas estão corretas. A não ser que não tenha o `@data` ou `@hora` dentro do comando que está montando.

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar a exceção exata? E, também, o conteúdo de `sqlInsertCabecalho`.

Comment: @jbueno efetuei as alterações

Comment: @bigown editei e acrescentei o detalhe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um erro de digitação, mude para:

```
VALUES (@nRequesicao, @nomeEmpresa, @colaborador, @data, @hora, @nota)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/VarQuery.cs).

Comment: @jbueno é sem dúvida um erro de uma estúpida distração minha, mas agora deparei-me com esta exceção: 'Additional information: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.'

Comment: Que banco de dados está usando? Se quer gravar em uma coluna *Timestamp*, precisa mandar para este formato, não pode mandar qualquer coisa.

Comment: @Kawaii Aí já é assunto para outra pergunta. Não tem nenhum problema você abrir mais de uma pergunta num curto intervalo. Se problema desta já foi resolvido, você marcar uma das respostas como correta no ✓ abaixo do número de votos. De qualquer forma, este erro provavelmente tem a ver com tipo de dados das colunas do banco. Quais o tipo das colunas `data` e `hora`?

Comment: Entendido, e muito obrigado!

Comment: @Kawaii se for fazer uma nova pergunta, não esqueça de informar o bano de dados e o tipo da coluna. Eu votei pra fechar a pergunta, porque ela é só um erro de digitação, não tem um problema com isso, mas não vai ajudar mais ninguém.

Answer (score 2):

É um erro de digitação, tem um **2** no lugar do **@** (`2nota`)

```
VALUES(@nRequesicao,@nomeEmpresa,@colaborador,@data,@hora,@nota)
```